# Are there many countries in which universities pay PhD students a wage comparable to a basic job in industry?

Tags: phd, funding, salary

I should soon complete my masters degree in engineering and have decided to apply for a PhD after I finish.

An issue I face is that I cannot afford to not receive a wage that I could for example get by going into industry. So far I have been very fortunate to study for free in Scotland and Switzerland - and during my time in Switzerland it became apparent that the PhD students not only didn't have to pay fees but in fact were employed as staff of the University and received a good wage. As a comparison in Scotland you would normally have your doctorate fees covered by the project funding but would only receive a modest stipend on which it would be a real struggle to get by upon fully depending on circumstance. Further, in other countries, I know it is normal to pay your fees for doing the PhD and receive no stipend whatsoever.

My question is: are there many other countries in which, as you do in Switzerland, you receive a staff wage comparable to a wage you would receive from going straight into a job in industry? The only other countries I'm aware of in which this is the culture are Denmark and Sweden.

Comment: Australia, in many cases. I do not pay tuition and also get a fortnightly stipend/wage/salary/whatever. Doesn't make me rich though.

Comment: If you are concerned that a Ph.D. stipend won't pay as much as a Masters in Engineering will get you in industry, then a Ph.D. is probably not the right career choice for you...

Comment: I suggest a change of title: "doctoral wage" sounds like you are asking specifically for places where PhD candidates get the wage of a doctoral degree holder (postdoc), instead of where they get a wage at all.

Comment: What discipline are we talking about? Reality is salaries in academia – especially pre-professoral – depend **a lot** on the field, even though in theory they shouldn't. So always state the discipline if asking about PhD and postdoc positions.

Comment: I tweaked title to try to match question in body. "i.e., the wage is equivalent to a basic job in industry"... Of course, I think an important point is exactly how you define a basic job in industry. I.e., you could define it as minimum wage. Or you could define it as something more general, but presumably it would depend on your industry.

Comment: As an aside, the term "wage" is perhaps a little loaded. Ultimately, its about how much money you get whether it is called  a "stipend", "scholarship", or "wage".

Comment: The question was formulated as a "make a big list" or "shopping" question, which are off-topic on this site.  I have adjusted it to instead be answerable in terms of how common or rare the practice is.

Comment: The big problem with that question is that there is no "wage you would receive from going straight into a job in industry". For instance in Austria, depending on your previous experience, negotiation skills, connections, luck, marketable skills, and a million other factors, your salary may be comparable to a PhD student salary or close to twice as high. Depending on who you talk to, PhD students are either hideously underpaid or reasonably well-off.

Comment: @HaoYe I wonder why every salary-related question on academia.SE always receives comments how an academic (and especially a PhD student) should not care about money. I think this is a seriously stifling and unhealthy way to approach this topic.

Comment: Isn't this question too broad? I mean, it will potentially attract as many different answers as there are countries with PhD programs, and none of them can really be "right" or "wrong".

Comment: PhD students in Switzerland do pay a fee, although a very modest one. The PhD salaries are significantly lower than the median salary for the country and significantly lower than any industry position, providing your field makes you employable (engineering, maths, etc.).

Comment: @xLeitix - there is a good reason from the US perspective.  In the US, the average professor makes substantially less than the average person in industry with a corresponding amount of experience.  Furthermore, doing a PhD has little if any worth in industry.  Hence from a purely economic perspective, doing a PhD is a bad economic choice.  As an Asst Professor, I have (within $2000/year) the same salary I had (in my 2nd year in industry) before entering grad school, and that's without accounting for more than 15 years of inflation.  I hated working in industry, so it was a reasonable choice.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I would speculate that there is a relationship between the indoctrination that academics are not supposed to care about money and the fact that academics are (as you say) underpaid. In Central Europe, where this seems much less common, a reputed full professor is certainly not badly paid in comparison to industry.

Comment: @xLeitix - I never said that an academic of a PhD student should not care about money. I do think, however, that it's unrealistic to expect to receive a PhD stipend equivalent to going into industry (which OP suggests is a dealbreaker: "I cannot afford to not receive a wage that I could for example get by going into industry.") If that were the case, there would be a lot more people doing PhDs, since there would be very little opportunity cost. Especially for engineering disciplines.

Comment: @HaoYe It is not unrealistic at all in some countries. This question seeks to identify those countries.

Comment: Remember that spending time doing a PHD will reduce how much industry will pay compared to someone that has spend the time getting "real life" experience.   Unless you can find a job that NEEDs what you learned while doing the PHd.

Comment: Why do people expect to get paid to spend time learning how to do research?    Would not any money spend on PHd students not get a better return on investment by having more post docs instead?

Comment: @Ian *"Why do people expect to get paid as a junior [something]?"* Because you are still delivering value to your company (the university, in that case), and should expect to be paid fairly for that. As for why you won't be having more postdocs instead - because a postdoc costs more and has a rather different job profile.

Comment: @HaoYe The "opportunity costs" of doing a PhD in my experience is that most people are simply happy to be done with studying after their undergrad :) that being said, in countries like Germany we indeed do see a lot more PhD students, many (or most?) of whom never intended to stay in academia. Many research groups get quite big around here.

Comment: @xLeitix it is not a question of indoctrination that makes academics accept a lower wage than industry, but rather simple supply and demand.  Academia produces too many qualified candidates for these positions and as a result there is significant downward wage pressure.  If you could not fill those positions you would see the wages rise.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure how much Scotland is different from the rest of the UK, but from my experience of UK PhD funding, I'm not sure why you're worried.

A standard PhD stipend is a little over £14,000 per year, paid quarterly. Fees are covered, and additional money can often be earned by taking on teaching or marking duties, up to about £1500 per year. Taking into account that students do not pay tax this is approximately equivalent to a salary of £17 or £18 thousand per year.

While I appreciate that circumstances may vary for different people, I wouldn't really call that

> a real struggle to get by upon

Outside of London, that is enough to rent a decent sized one bedroom flat or share a nice house, pay your bills, take a nice holiday and still have the weekly cash to go out for dinner or drinks. In London, the stipend is increased but I don't have personal experience of the living expenses there, so it may be different.

As I said, circumstances may be difficult for some people, but most universities will have support for childcare or special needs, so unless you are trying to support a family as the sole earner, I don't think it's really a worry.

Comment: You're slightly optimsitic on what it would get you, I suggest (other major cities can be quite expensive too).  But the fact that it's tax free makes a huge difference.

Comment: Not really, I'm speaking from personal experience here, and I live in a major city. I'm not saying you can take loads of expensive holidays and buy whatever you want, but you don't have to live on a shoestring. For a single person, or someone sharing with other employed people, money isn't really a worry.

Comment: @FJC I can further extend. I also live in a major U.K. city and also have two children and a partner who's also a student. I can't say I've had any worries during my PhD, we've been able to live quite comfortably with me doing a bit of teaching.

Comment: Just for full disclosure, are you a UK, EU, or overseas student? Non-EU students often have a *radically* different experience to obtaining PhD studentships. This varies by field, I imagine (so you should state your area), but in the physical sciences most of the main funding channels are EU-only at best (though of course that is subject to change in the next couple of years). As an overseas student, a PhD is often an exercise in raising £20k+ per year, plus living expenses, with no UK channel willing or able to shell out.

Comment: @FJC The OP was not asking about surviving with PhD salary, he was asking about the PhD salary that was "comparable to a basic job in industry". 15K - 18K a year is not in any way comparable to a basic job in industry. And do you know that in order to become permanent resident, your (Tier 2 visa) salary needs to be at least 35k. In London, where I did my PhD, the basic job in industry in my field (Junior Software Engineer) starts with 45k for fresh graduate. Of course, folks at Google, Facebook etc get much more.

Comment: @E.P. Yes I am a UK student, but I was assuming that the issue is not about getting the studentship, but living on it when you've got it. It's fairly obvious that if you can't get the funding then you're not going to have any money. My experience is in Physical Sciences, and yes the number of studentships available depends on your citizenship, but I don't think value of the stipend varies much between funding bodies. All UK, EU or non-EU students I know get about £14000 per year.

Comment: @v107 I'm not aware what the OP's idea of a basic salary in industry would actually be, but when I was applying for graduate jobs a few years ago £17k wasn't out of the ball park. I agree that there are some areas where graduate starting salaries are higher, but I don't think £45k is the standard. Maybe we should ask the OP to give a figure for the salary they would expect in their area?
On your point about visas, I think PhD students don't get permanent resident visas, just a temporary one for the duration of studies, so that wouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: Just to add on his: I am an UK PhD student and I did save enough with this money to go to a trip to Japan for 3 weeks. This salary won't be good for having a family, but its OK for 1 person

Comment: The OP hasn't specified *why* they cannot afford a low income. People here are making assumptions that they want a lavish lifestyle (or that they have overestimated the cost of living), but consider that they might (for example) be supporting a family.

Answer (score 16):

In Germany PhD students are also usually employees. Most professors have one or a few PhD positions to fill and also third party funding often comes for PhD positions (e.g. from the DFG or from the BMBF). This means they have a regular job and all social security. The pay is good **but** first it is far from what one could get in the industry (of course, depending on the field...), second you are often employed half time, three quarters or something different, and third you'll have teaching duties to fulfill. Either way you can make a living as a PhD student (even part time) but you  can  probably not afford a fancy lifestyle with a big house or a new car.

Also note, that you can also do your PhD on some kind of scholarship which come without social security (e.g. from some foundations but also some departments have a system for PhD scholarships).

Comment: be careful, not all PhD Students are emplyees in germany. And, quite a lot of Professors don't give their phd "jobs" to foreign students (this includes all students from other universities than theirs) if they don't know them. They wait for students with stipends. And Stpendiates don't have all the social securty. Also, some groups, due to lack of funding or greed only pay their phds a minimum wage like a "Studentenjob" which is around 800 €

Comment: To complete what @Julian wrote: The other end of the spectrum is fields where PhD students with anything other than a 100% employment in their institute are basically unheard of. So, there is indeed a lot of variation across places and fields.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thank you. I forgot to meantion, that my experience is mostly limited to Chemistry, Physics and Biology an some uniersities.

Comment: @Julian: Since the asker is in Engineering, my experience is that he'd be closer to the 100% employment end of the scale.

Comment: @Julian Off-topic, but you can avoid the `code` formatting if you use the apostrophe ' instead of the grave accent `.

Comment: @Julian you can also use a backslash to escape the \` using \\` to avoid getting code formatting

Comment: I have done a PhD in physics, in Germany, and I can ensure that it actually the opposite. Most PhD students get department scholarships and not government contracts, unless specified otherwise in some special cases. The former usually amount to 1/3 of an industry salary and contain no health and medical insurance, that has to be covered additionally.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Sure, there are PhD students on scholarships (and I'll add that to my answer). But this is far from the norm in all the fields I know (and also in Physics). I do not doubt that you experienced that "most PhD students get department scholarships", but this has to be some special environment.

Comment: @Julian In Computer Science it's quite common to have 100% employment. Which is rather necessary because that's in my experience still the lowest possible end of the scale - if you're good, you can easily get double or more in the industry (and that's ignoring bonuses..). Really, nobody gets into academics to get rich.

Comment: Some data about computer science in Germany - you'll usually get 100% TVL-E13 which is ~44.000€/year gross and at least 27.000€/year net (social security, pension, health care already deducted). This is comparable with the median starting salary in industry, but if you've been offered a PhD position, you can expect to get more in industry. Of course the industry starting salary for PhDs is also higher. Financially, it doesn't make much difference whether you do a PhD if you plan to go into industry anyway, because 3 years experience will be worth about the same as a PhD in my experience.

Comment: Is it really common for those half or two thirds time students to actually do half time or two thirds time work? From what I've seen, there are people who work more something like 120% of a normal working day regardless of payment. I'm not sure if this is an isolated culture only in my area or if it's sort of expected.

Comment: @AndrejaKo That's another question...

Comment: @AndrejaKo: They work 60%, the other 60% is "studying&learning". Also they get only 20 days off per year, other employees in the TVL scales usually 30.

Answer (score 11):

In Norway, the standard PhD salary is around NOK 420.000 which is about USD 52.500 per year. This will give you around NOK 24.500 or USD 3.000 per month after tax. In addition you will get about NOK 70.000 to cover travel expences etc.

Comment: In my university in Norway it used to be NOK 30.000 for travel expenses etc. per year, otherwise the numbers agree. Note that USD/NOK rate fluctuates considerably: it was 5.50-6.00 four years ago but is 7.50-8.85 this year. So it used to be more like USD 4,500 per month after tax, which was a really nice deal if you compare globally. Of course, the prices in Norway were high back then, too, as measured in USD.

Comment: But, you also spend Norwegian quantities of moneey on groceries, travel, leisure, etc. (but it's still a very good deal).

Answer (score 10):

I can attest to the Netherlands and Belgium being on this list. PhD students are (normally!) considered employees of the university and are paid salary. As far as I know this is the case when the project has secured funding.

The questions surrounding the project funding are generally more difficult - i.e. in some cases the student needs to find an own source of funding - either another institution providing funding (scholarships etc) or a company.

Comment: The Netherlands is slowly moving away from this model, and replacing a wage with a stipend. Supposedly the same monthly income, but without the full legal protection of an employee contract.

Comment: @MSalters: not only without the legal protection. Also without the wage increases, no pension, no social insurances and without a bench free (if you're in a lab you have to hope your colleagues have some money to spare so you can buy stuff).

Answer (score 7):

In Switzerland, PhD students in areas where there is a high demand and relatively easy to find a job (physics, computer science) are paid a salary less but still comparable to that a company can offer for the new master without any previous employment. Master degree is required for PhD.

For areas where it is more difficult to find a job, it is formally half time employment (so 50 %) but realistically a PhD student still stays a complete working day in laboratory. It may change over time and be laboratory dependent on which of these two rules applies.

Answer (score 7):

I would add Mexico to the list.

In STEM, a PhD grant from the national council for sciences and technology (conacyt) is [6 times the minimum salary](http://conacyt.gob.mx/index.php/becas-y-posgrados/becas-nacionales), which is equivalent to the starting salary of a freshly graduated engineer. Today, this amount is equivalent to around USD $700 a month, tax free, and enough to live correctly in Mexico City.

Some universities could give other grants. For instance, the UNAM has a grant program for students not in areas covered by conacyt. The amount of the grant is equivalent ([See the UNAM website](http://www.posgrado.unam.mx/es/main-menu/alumnos-de-maestria-y-doctorado-de-la-unam)).

I would add that in public universities tuition is basically free.

Answer (score 4):

In Hungary, when applying for PhD, you can decide whether to apply for a stipend (paid by the government) or pay yourself. Some universities have limitations, like they don't allow you to have a stipend when working full-time, but this is not universal. If you apply for it and your results are good enough, you will get paid for 2+2 years in the current system (I think if you don't finish your dissertation by the end of that, you have to pay back some of it).

As of today, this means 140 000 HUF for the first 2 years and 180 000 after. The minimum wage is about 74 000 HUF after taxes. Also, engineering students frequently participate in projects at the university or industrial partners, which can add a lot.

Comment: To translate that: 140,000 HUF are about 450 euros. Living in Hungary is a bit more affordable, but not that much.

Answer (score 3):

In Italy, PhD students are paid a net amount of at least 1000 Euros per month (the sum is dictated by government), in case their admission would be with a scholorship. In some cases, research groups might add some additional money to the 1000 Euros to further support their PhD student. It can get up to 1500. In industry, a newly graduated engineer makes roughly about 1500 euros per month after taxation during first 3 years of employment.

Comment: Right. Also the university itself can additional money bringing sometimes the PhD scholarship around 1300 €/month.

Answer (score 3):

In Belgium, you get a decent salary during your Ph.D., but you will not pay taxes on it, so you will not be able to profit from tax advantages. (e.g. if you have a loan, you will not receive tax refunds).

Answer (score 3):

It depends even on the field of study and the deaprtment heads.

In Czech republic, PhD students are paid a stipend and can be paid from the project they are part of.

In one department the students are paid the "state" stipend only, and it is not comparable even with minimum wage. In another department, with strong research background, the students are paid comparable to average wage. Both are part of same university.

Answer (score 3):

It is about 1700-1800 Euro per month in Austria after taxes for 
Computer Science or Electrical Engineering. (14x a year)
 This is about the median income in Austria, but still a little less, than industry pays.

Answer (score 3):

In Argentina you can apply for a full scholarship from mainly two government agencies: [CONICET](http://www.agencia.mincyt.gob.ar/) and [AGENCIA](http://www.agencia.mincyt.gob.ar/). Beware that everyone can apply but not everyone gets it, although the number of scholarships given is rather generous.

I think there is an age limit also (<30 years? Something like that).

The current scholarship is a little less than U$S1000 monthly, which is semi-decent given the cost of living in this country.

Answer (score 3):

In Sweden, most PhD students are employees with standard benefits: five weeks vacation, paid family leave, sick leave, social security, etc. There are considerable variations in salary depending on your field, university, and how long you've been employed. The salary range is roughly around 20k SEK/mo (~2100€, just starting out in the humanities) to around 34k SEK/mo (~3550€, close to dissertation at top paying STEM universities) before taxes. Incomes in this bracket are taxed at roughly 25%.

For comparison, the median salary in Sweden is somewhere around 28 000 SEK/mo.

There are no additional fees for being a PhD student, but you will usually be expected to spend part of your time teaching or doing other departmental duties.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, there are many places where PhD fees are waved and where many students receive some form of scholarship/stipend/wage. Thus, it seems that there are several issues:

- Are fees waved, deferred, or paid?
- Do you get given money to do the PhD and if so how much?
- Are you considered an employee and therefore get additional benefits?
- How much additional work (e.g., teaching, research assistant, etc.) is allowed or advised while doing PhD and how much money does that generate?
- What are you defining as the income you could earn in industry and how close do you have to get to that income for the PhD to be considered equivalent?

I'll use the case of a PhD in Australia as an example:

- Most local students will have their fees waved
- Perhaps half of all PhD students are on a scholarship
- The median wage of a full-time worker is about AUD$60,000, which at a guess is roughly $48,000 after tax.
- A PhD scholarship would be about AUD$26,000 tax free.
- If you did some tutoring work up to the generally allowed level (perhaps 6-8 hours per week averaged throughout the year) you might earn another AUD$10,000 which wouldn't be taxed because you're below the tax free threshold.

So, in summary, you are earning $36,000 after tax compared to median  wage of about $48,000 after tax. You're not getting retirement benefits and many of the other employment benefits you would get with a full-time wage.

Alternatively, you might be able to work part-time and do the PhD part-time. Many scholarships require full-time completion. But if you are able to get scholarship and work part-time. Then you might be able to put together something approaching median wage. That said, the whole process would take longer, and you wont necessarily be in a better financial position at the end, had you gone full-time, and started your post-PhD career sooner.

So in summary, I guess it depends on exactly where you set the frame of reference and how you combine scholarship, other income, and the potential post-PhD income.

Answer (score 2):

In France PhD has salary of about 1300 or 1500 euro net per month, but then student has to pay annual tax:

- If he/she earns 1300 euro/month, tax is about 200 euro
- If the net salary is > 1500 euro/month, tax is > 1200 euro

Also every PhD student pays fees to university, which is about 400 euro/year.
France is a very socialistic country, as you see from taxes above, but PhD students are not eligible for any social help.

And consider, please, that apartment rent in Paris region (Ile-de-France) is expensive, a decent studio not very far from university costs more than 500 euro/month.

Comment: Social help, and taxes, vary greatly with your personal situation: my wife, my newborn son & I could decently live in Paris during my PhD, having only my salary. Our rent was expensive (~800€) but we had a couple of social help, and paid close to no taxes.

Answer (score 2):

I am limiting my answer to the scope of engineering PhD programs. In the USA, the stipend number varies greatly by geographical area, university prestige, private or government funding, and program of studies. I know of universities that pay annual PhD stipends from USD $10k up to USD $55k. These are normally dictated by the amount the university determines as "cost of attendance."

This amount generally caps the available financial aid (in the form of scholarships, fellowships, grants, etc.) that the university can provide to a student. Of course, there are external sources but that wasn't part of the OP question.

In my impression, the (roughly) top 50 engineering programs will pay a decent enough stipend for a single person to live comfortably (rent a private studio/apartment, eat out regularly, make car payment, etc.) without splurging.

Comment: I did an MS in a respected (but not famous) STEM program in the western USA - Master's and PhD students who obtained a stipend from their projects (most did not) received somewhere from $10-20K annually, and also had their tuition covered. This was enough to cover housing and food in the area, and a few luxuries, but not much else after taxes. Those who went directly into industry in the same state were paid anywhere from $40-70K starting salary depending on their exact field.

Answer (score 2):

In USA, if you are lucky (good) enough to get full funding, it'll cover your living costs if you are single and you probably earn more than the national median. But that's an order of magnitude off from what you can potentially earn. As someone who is thinking of going for a PhD you probably qualify for high earning jobs. This totally depends on your degree.

Say in Computer Science, where I come from, doing a PhD makes no financial sense in 99.999999% of the cases. Take this from someone who went through a long PhD program.